# 3 second long queries on 5.8 MB database

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm running this query;

```
SELECT p.*, 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.upload_date) upload_date_unix, 
       ph.*, 
       c.category_name, 
       c.slug, 
       (SELECT Count(vote) 
        FROM   picture_votes 
        WHERE  picture_id = p.picture_id) vote_count 
FROM   pictures p 
       LEFT JOIN photographers ph 
              ON ph.photographer_id = p.photographer_id 
       LEFT JOIN categories c 
              ON c.category_id = p.category_id 
WHERE  p.approved = 1 
       AND ( p.picture_id = p.album_id 
              OR p.album_id IS NULL ) 
GROUP  BY p.picture_id 
ORDER  BY p.upload_date DESC 
LIMIT  99
```

And the query takes ~2-3 seconds. If I remove `(SELECT count(vote) FROM picture_votes WHERE picture_id = p.picture_id) vote_count` the query is like 0.01 seconds. How come it slows the query down so much? `picture_votes` is only 25,000 rows.

How can I change the query to include the vote count for every picture?

Here's the [explain to the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6OVJ.png).

Comment: How long does the nested `SELECT` statement (from `picture_votes`) take on its own?  Does it involve a table scan?  Do you have proper indexes setup for `picture_id`?

Comment: Post the explain for this query

Comment: [Explain for the query](http://i.imgur.com/RkJVwgf.png)

Comment: I don't see a pv alias is that picture votes? If so index vote column on picture_votes

Comment: I don't see why that `GROUP BY` is needed. What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your subquery add one more join on `picture_votes`

```
SELECT p.*, 
       Unix_timestamp(p.upload_date)      upload_date_unix, 
       ph.*, 
       c.category_name, 
       c.slug, 
       Count(vote)  vote_count           
FROM   pictures p 
       LEFT JOIN picture_votes pv ON ( p.picture_id = pv.picture_id )
       LEFT JOIN photographers ph 
              ON ph.photographer_id = p.photographer_id 
       LEFT JOIN categories c 
              ON c.category_id = p.category_id 
WHERE  p.approved = 1 
       AND ( p.picture_id = p.album_id 
              OR p.album_id IS NULL ) 
GROUP  BY p.picture_id 
ORDER  BY p.upload_date DESC 
LIMIT  99
```

Comment: This is how I initially did it. This increases the query by ~1 second.

Comment: @WillB add these three indexes and see if it works `ALTER TABLE pictures ADD INDEX index_photographer_id   (photographer_id);
ALTER TABLE pictures ADD INDEX index_category_id    (category_id );
ALTER TABLE picture_votes  ADD INDEX index_picture_id     (category_id );`

Comment: Thanks @M Khalid Junaid! I only added an index on `picture_votes(picture_id)` and it helped a lot (from ~2.5s to ~0.04s).

Comment: Indexes are our best friends usually columns involve in where clauses or in on clauses needs to be indexed

Answer (score 0):

Based on the explain for the query, you need index the vote column on picture_votes.
Whenever you have NULL under possible_keys it means that MySQL could not use a relevant index.

Comment: Okay. How should I index it?

Comment: You can run 
CREATE INDEX vote
ON picture_votes (vote);

Comment: Adding an index on vote did not help. However, adding an index on `picture_votes(picture_id)` helped a lot. Query time went from 2.5 to 0.04.